# Deleting a programmatically added control from a Grid in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Straight forward stuff, but most answers I've seen are outdated and are giving me errors and I'm new to C#.

After programmatically inserting a button:

```
var myButton = new Button();
```

How can I then delete it?

I've tried:

```
myButton.Delete();
myButton.Remove();

// These both gives me a 'MainPage' does not have a property Controls error.
this.Controls.remove(myButton);
myContainer.Controls.remove(myButton);
```

---

Edit:

Trying `myButton.Parent.Controls.Remove(myButton)` gives:

> Error CS1061  'DependencyObject' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'DependencyObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you tried `myButton.Parent.Controls.Remove(myButton)`?

Comment: I gave it a shot, no luck. Error in the new edit.

Comment: if its WPF then it is `Children`

Comment: @MartinStaufcik That was it, thanks! If you make that an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF the collection name `Children`

```
myButton.Parent.Children.Remove(myButton)
```